# Unaesthetic busy/loading animation under LXDE / Openbox

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian, window-managers, xserver, display-manager

I set up my Raspberry Pi with Raspbian and LXDE as display manager. Now whenever I start an application [this animation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0UvCU.jpg) is shown in the top right corner of the screen.

Does anybody know, what triggers this animation and if it can be disabled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually means that you're short of voltage.  See this forum post [Under-voltage warnings](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=82373).

> The B+ has an under voltage detect trigger which results in the power led going off when voltage drops below about 4.65V.
>   The signal is also available on a gpio line (GPIO35).
>   Latest firmware update will display a warning symbol in top right of display when this is detected.
>   It will also disable turbo mode while the warning is displayed to try to reduce the chances of crashing.
>   I've also added a warning symbol to the existing over-temperature condition (> 85'C), which also disabled turbo mode.
>   Currently the symbols are:
>   - Red square: over-temperature
>   - Rainbow square: under-voltage

Typically I get it if I'm using a poor quality power supply or a rubbish micro USB cable.